# How to retrieve the ‘List<myObject>' realm array to array from realm model class?

Tags: swift, realm

My realm model class look like

```
class RoomRealmModel : Object {

    dynamic var id: String = ""
    var details = List<RoomDetailRealmModel>()

  func saveItem() {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            realm.beginWrite()
            realm.add(self, update: true)
            try realm.commitWrite()
           } catch{}
    }

}
class  RoomDetailRealmModel : Object{

    dynamic var detailId: String = ""
    dynamic var displayText: String = ""
}
```

I want to retrieve 'details' from the following.

```
details = RLMArray<RoomDetailRealmModel> <0x600000114f40> (
        [0] RoomDetailRealmModel {
            text = hello;
            Counters = 9;
            ParentID = ;
            detailId = 33;
            displayText = hello ;
        }
    );
```

I always get empty like in my console

```
(lldb) po (destinationData?[index]?.details)!
List<RoomDetailRealmModel> <0x600000853620> (

)
```

I am updating ‘details’ list via realm update command. I always get realm array.But I want to retrieve array type from realm array.Please help me, how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain [myObject] instead of List you can do something like this:

```
var array: [myObject] = [myObject]()

for object in myObjectList {
    array.append(object)
}
```

Where myObjectList is List.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a regular Swift `Array` from a Realm `List` by calling the initializer of `Array` accepting a `Sequence`, since `List` conforms to the sequence protocol.

So you can simply do

```
let room = RoomRealmModel()
let roomDetailsArray = Array(room.details)
```